# GA4 & Google Pixel - Email open event showing in real-time, but not in reports?

Tags: google-pixel, google-analytics-4

I have created a new event (hand_therapy_open) in GA4 that will track each time when a newsletter email is opened using the following google pixel:

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=2&amp;tid=G-##########&amp;cid=555&amp;t=event&amp;en=hand_therapy_open&amp;ec=contacts_email&amp;ea=open" alt="">
```

I can see the event is being triggered in real-time data:

[image]

But when viewing reports or events it does not show:
[image]

Any suggestions? I have waited over 24 hours for events to track.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution we found was to convey the pixel traffic through our servers and do a server-server post.