# Hit builder event not showing on GA4 reports, but only in real time reports

Tags: html, email, analytics, google-analytics-4

I need to track email opens in GA4, I have managed to do so by including an img in the HTML code of the email. When I recieve the email and open it the event is fired and GA4 tracks it. It is shown in real time report, however i can only see events in the past 30mins and when i go to check event report in interaction, GA4 would only show standard events (such as page_view, user_engagement, etc), but not this event.

The image i am using is:
 `<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=2&tid=G-LRSP6DG2KX&cid=&t=event&el=Abrio&dp=Leyó&ni=1&en=Leyó">`

And GA4 recieves an event "Leyó"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOOqr.png)

And as you can see there is no Leyó event in event Report

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfc8G.png)

I tried configuring custom events in GA4, such as firing a email_open event whenever GA4 recieves an event which name is Leyó. But it won´t work as i expected. I also tried to change t parameter in the img tag, to page_view hoping that GA4 would track a page_view event every time I open the email, but it didn´t work.

I expect to track emails opens in my campaign so I can build analytics report for the marketing team.

Comment: There are a lot of open posts asking similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76874978/ga4-google-pixel-email-open-event-showing-in-real-time-but-not-in-reports.  I believe GA4 isn't setup to leverage the pixel tracking like it was in UA. There is a way to pseudo achieve it but they all have ran into the "only visible in 30min looks". Something about it being a server side tracking mechanism...